# ChildNode[3] to obtain description for the correspondence item

Tags: c#, asp.net, child-nodes

When the Get button is clicked, I have to Compare title of each item element, If it is the same as item selected in ddlTitle and Display the child element  in the label lbldesc

However, the description does not appear when i click the button after selecting title from the dropdownlist

```
  protected void BtnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlNodeList itemsList = RSSDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");//get a list of item node
        if (itemsList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode eachItem in itemsList) //for each item node
            {
                XmlNodeList itemNode = eachItem.ChildNodes;
                foreach (XmlNode itemchild in itemNode)     //Access title node
                {
                    if (itemchild.Name == "title")
                    {
                        lbldesc.Text = (itemchild.ChildNodes[3].InnerText);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `itemchild.ChildNodes[3]` ... does all child 4 nodes? may be the `InnerText` property is empty

Comment: From your posted code, if the label does not display any text, then it seems the 4-th child of the title node does not have any inner text... Please provide an (anonymized) excerpt from your XML data for the list of <item> elements.

Comment: Here is the xml !! http://www.channelnewsasia.com/rssfeeds/8395954

Comment: Basically in <item> there are tags like <title>, <description> and so on inside.... !! from the business link in http://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/rss